# ¿Como puedo enviar un array de una página en un hosting a una página en localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, array

Resulta que tengo un array en mi página almacena en un hosting  y quiero enviar ese array a una página en localhost, lo que quiero hacer es obtener el array desde mi página en el hosting y enviarlo a mi página en localhost donde tengo el código para imprimir los datos del array

Comment: Desde el servidor va a ser muy complicado que puedas enviar algo a localhost, como mínimo, necesitarías una IP fija y algunas otras cosas. Es mucho más fácil si creas un script en localhost que haga una petición al servidor para obtener esa información y, si no sabes cuándo se va a generar, entonces puedes usar tareas programadas para que se ejecute cada determinado tiempo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Parecería que necesitarías exponer los datos en un sitio para consumirlos en otro, a modo de API o Servicio Web. Si es de servidor a servidor quizá lo mejor sería usar cURL. Si es de servidor a cliente, entonces puedes usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Lo cierto es que el contexto no aparece expuesto con claridad en tu pregunta. De todos modos, la pregunta debe estar basada en código concreto, el sitio no admite preguntas/respuestas basadas en opiniones.

Comment: Creo que deberías hacerlo a la inversa, de localhost solicitar la información a tu hosting